# Writing fractional numbers in Java or Android

Tags: java, android

I am rendering the HTML into my project to create this type of image as follows:

[image: desired output]

So i write this code as below:

```
<big>1</big>
<sup>
  <sup>
    <small>
      <small>1</small>
    </small>
  </sup>
</sup>
  /
<sub>
  <small>3</small>
</sub>
```

But the output looks like this:

[image: actual output]

You can see the gap between the number 1 and '/' and also between '/' and 3. any idea how to remove it?

**Solution:**

```
Just number values changes

<big>1</big><sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>10</sub>
```

which will look like this as in figure. [image]

Hope this will help someone.Thanks guys for your support.

Comment: If the font supports it, perhaps you would just use the one-third symbol: ⅓

Comment: @aioobe i used font tag before it did not support so i went for big and small tags

Comment: I'll reformulate in an answer...

Comment: You don't need the font-tag. See my answer.

Comment: Try lowering the font size when printing fractions.

Comment: @st0le M i using font tag in my given question? font tag is not supporting here.so i m using big and small tags.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're seeing gaps in between the numerator, separator, and denominator is because you're trying to render three different characters in a plain text string, one after another:

[image]

Since you want the fractional elements to behave a little bit differently than standard text behaves, you'll have to look at using something designed especially for displaying these types of symbols.  You might want to look at MathML (specifically, the portion dealing with [bevelled elements in fractions](http://www.xmlmind.com/tutorials/MathML/index.html#d0e324), and something like [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/index.html) to do the actual rendering.

Comment: Not likely.  Native MathML support exists in Firefox (http://caniuse.com/mathml), but most other browsers are unable to render it natively, including the Android browser.  It sounds like you'll have to render the fractional components to .pngs with JEuclid, and then include them in the page you're displaying.

Comment: ok thanks for the help,but i want to use directly inside the code.

Comment: I found one solution as i put in my question above.See it plz

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really address you're issue, and I'll admit I haven't done this in Android yet, though I don't see why it wouldn't work, but what I've done in these sorts of situations before was...cheat. I am a programmer after all ;). Take the text you're having problems with and dynamically generate a nice looking graphic for it, then display that graphic. Designer's have been doing this forever as well, using Flash font substitutions.

Some problems just aren't easily solved the "right" way.
hth

Comment: I found one solution as i put in my question above.See it plz

Comment: I know we can use images.But your application will so many images then this is not good solution.Because android application gets slow with many images.